# How to check if call exist in another Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I have two sheets:

1. Sheet1: which contains URLs in A2:A
2. Sheet2, which contains URLs in A2:A

Part of URLs from `Sheet1` also exist in `Sheet2`. I'd like to place formula in `Sheet1!B2:B`, where as a result I would get `YES` or `NO` which would point if URL is present in both shets. How can this be done?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the following formula in Sheet1!B2:

```
=arrayformula(not(isna(match(A2:A, Sheet2!A2:A, 0))))
```

You will get TRUE and FALSE instead of YES or NO but I hope that's close enough, and better if you want to use the results for further formula work. If you insist on textual "YES" or "NO", convert the not() call to if(isna(..), "NO", "YES").